# Make a scalable Christmas Tree

Tags: popularity-contest

Your challenge: Make a Christmas tree. The size must be choosable by some input method, but doesn't have to be directly related to any part of the tree; however, larger inputs should produce a larger tree.

How can you make it? You can make the tree any way you like, other than by printing the [unicode character for the tree](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f384/index.htm), such as ouputting an image, ascii art, with other aspects, etc. Whatever you do, remember that this is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so be creative.

The answer with the most upvotes by the end of December wins, but I'll accept another if it gets higher

Comment: Nice question ;)

Comment: A pity decorations weren't mandatory!

Comment: @Lohoris I think it is good that they aren't mandatory. This way, people can do what they want, and those brilliant fractal trees are legitimate answers.

Comment: @Quincunx you could add decorations even to fractal trees...

Comment: @Lohoris yes, but they are plenty as is. The author of those trees could add decorations if they'd like to, but I'd rather not require it.

Comment: @dystroy: it sais printing out the unicode tree is a no-go. Anything else (including ascii art) is fine.

Comment: @SztupY I've reread and you're right. Then it seems you're allowed to fetch an image with wget :\

Comment: @Quincunx, Is ASCII art allowed?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, of course, as stated in the question.

Comment: Almost makes me want to take input as if it was a [p-adic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) just to make it confusing as to what "larger input should produce larger output" actually means.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

### Python

A fractal Christmas tree using the turtle package:

[image]

```
n = input()*1.

from turtle import *
speed("fastest")
left(90)
forward(3*n)
color("orange", "yellow")
begin_fill()
left(126)
for i in range(5):
    forward(n/5)
    right(144)
    forward(n/5)
    left(72)
end_fill()
right(126)

color("dark green")
backward(n*4.8)
def tree(d, s):
    if d <= 0: return
    forward(s)
    tree(d-1, s*.8)
    right(120)
    tree(d-3, s*.5)
    right(120)
    tree(d-3, s*.5)
    right(120)
    backward(s)
tree(15, n)
backward(n/2)

import time
time.sleep(60)
```

n is the size parameter, the shown tree is for n=50.  Takes a minute or two to draw.

Comment: This looks lovely `:)`

Answer (score 76):

#### JavaScript

[image]

Show the animated tree [online](http://jsfiddle.net/62eaL/1/).

```js
var size = 400;

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = size;
canvas.height = size;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var p3d = [];

var p = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 0];

for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    p3d.push([p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3]]);
    var t = Math.random();
    if (t<0.4) {
        _y = 0.4 * p[1];
        _x = 0.1 * p[0];
        _z = 0.6 * p[2];
        var r = Math.floor(3*t/0.4)/3.0;
        var rc = Math.cos(Math.PI*2.0*r);
        var rs = Math.sin(Math.PI*2.0*r);
        p[1] = _x+0.1*r+0.5*_y*_y;
        p[0] = _y*rc+_z*rs;
        p[2] = _z*rc-_y*rs;
        p[3] = 0.2*t + 0.8*p[3];
    } else {
        p[1] = 0.2 + 0.8*p[1];
        p[0] = 0.8 * p[0];
        p[2] = 0.8 * p[2];
        p[3] = 0.2 + 0.8*p[3];
    }
}

var rot = 0.0;

function render() {
    rot = rot + 0.1;
    var rc = Math.cos(rot);
    var rs = Math.sin(rot);

    ctx.strokeStyle='#FF7F00';
    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(size/2,size/8);
    ctx.lineTo(size/2,size*15/16);
    ctx.stroke();

    var img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, size, size);
    for (var j = 0; j < size*size; j++) {
        img.data[4*j+0] = 0.5*img.data[4*j+0];
        img.data[4*j+1] = 0.5*img.data[4*j+1];
        img.data[4*j+2] = 0.5*img.data[4*j+2];
        img.data[4*j+3] = 255;
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < p3d.length; i++) {
        var px = p3d[i][0];
        var py = 0.5 - p3d[i][1];
        var pz = p3d[i][2];
        var col = Math.floor(128.0*p3d[i][3]);
        
        var _x = rc*px + rs*pz;
        var _z = rc*pz - rs*px;

        var z = 3.0 * size / (_z + 4.0);
        var x = size / 2 + Math.round(_x * z);        
        var y = size / 2 + Math.round(py * z);

        if(x>=0&&y>=0&&x<size&&y<size) {
            img.data[4 * (y * size + x) + 0] = col;
            img.data[4 * (y * size + x) + 1] = 128+col;
            img.data[4 * (y * size + x) + 2] = col;
            img.data[4 * (y * size + x) + 3] = 255;
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
}

setInterval(render, 1000 / 30);
```

Comment: I like it, but you should add a trunk.

Comment: @Fels added trunk

Comment: This is very impressive, but what's up with those green pixels circling the tree? I didn't realize that Santa had little green elves who can fly. (they do not detract from the beauty of your answer, but I wonder where they came from)

Comment: @Quincunx: They seem to be initial sample points from before the iteration converges. [Skipping the first 100 points](http://jsfiddle.net/62eaL/13/) gets rid of them.

Comment: Really cool, but it doesn't _quite_ look like a Christmas tree. It looks more like a stick with a few fern leaves attached to it. Also, could you make the view slowly scroll along the y axis, so the 3D-ness is more apparent?

Answer (score 75):

Yet another *Mathematica / Wolfram Language* tree based on [Vitaliy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16358/11224):

```
PD = .5;
s[t_, f_] := t^.6 - f
dt[cl_, ps_, sg_, hf_, dp_, f_, flag_] :=
    Module[{sv, basePt},
           {PointSize[ps],
            sv = s[t, f];
            Hue[cl (1 + Sin[.02 t])/2, 1, .3 + sg .3 Sin[hf sv]],
            basePt = {-sg s[t, f] Sin[sv], -sg s[t, f] Cos[sv], dp + sv};
            Point[basePt],
           If[flag,
              {Hue[cl (1 + Sin[.1 t])/2, 1, .6 + sg .4 Sin[hf sv]], PointSize[RandomReal[.01]],
               Point[basePt + 1/2 RotationTransform[20 sv, {-Cos[sv], Sin[sv], 0}][{Sin[sv], Cos[sv], 0}]]},
              {}]
          }]

frames = ParallelTable[
                       Graphics3D[Table[{
                                         dt[1, .01, -1, 1, 0, f, True], dt[.45, .01, 1, 1, 0, f, True],
                                         dt[1, .005, -1, 4, .2, f, False], dt[.45, .005, 1, 4, .2, f, False]},
                                        {t, 0, 200, PD}],
                                  ViewPoint -> Left, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.3}, 
                                  ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1},
                                  ViewCenter -> {{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.55}}, Boxed -> False,
                                  PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}, {0, 20}}, Background -> Black],
                       {f, 0, 1, .01}];

Export["tree.gif", frames]
```

[image: Christmas tree]

Comment: This is the best one!!

Answer (score 61):

### Javascript

[image: Output of given code sample]

This is my first code golf!

```
var a=40,b=8,c=13,o="<div style='font-family:monospace;text-align:center;color:#094'>",w=1,x=0,y="|#|<br>";for(i=1;i<a;i++){for(j=0;j<w;j++){x%c==0?o+="<span style='color:#D00'>O</span>":o+="+";x++;}i%b==0?w-=4:w+=2;o+="<br>";}document.write(o+"<span style='color:#640'>"+y+y+y+"</span></div>");
```

It comes in at 295 Characters.

The size and decoration of the tree is set by the a,b,c variables:

- a sets the amount of rows in the tree
- b sets the amount of rows between decreases in width (set low for a skinny tree, high for a fat tree). Must be greater than or equal to 3.
- c sets the amount of baubles (set zero for none, 1 for only baubles, higher numbers for less dense placement of baubles)

It looks best when a is a multiple of b, as in the example.

Paste into the console to create a tree. Looks better from far away!

Comment: reduced to 264 `a=40,b=8,c=13,o="<p style='font:monospace;color:#094' align='center'>",w=1,x=0,y="|#|<br>";for(i=1;i<a;i++){for(j=0;j<w;j++){x%c==0?o+="<b style='color:red'>O</b>":o+="+";x++;}i%b==0?w-=4:w+=2;o+="<br>";}document.write(o+"<b style='color:#640'>"+y+y+y+"</b></p>");`

Comment: You are really golfing on a popularity contest? Wow, I would have written nice readable code (easier to code in). +1

Comment: ungh. You're using `doc.write`? No +1 from me.

Comment: @JanDvorak, Why not? I'd thought this is golfing.....

Answer (score 61):

## Javascript

Quasirealistic fully 3D procedural fir tree generator.

Featuring: extensive configuration with even more configuration options present in code; a zigzagy trunk; branching branches; growth animation; rotation of a fully grown tree.

Not featuring: jQuery, Underscore.js or any other library; hardware dependency - only canvas support is required; messy code (at least that was the intention)

**Live page:** http://fiddle.jshell.net/honnza/NMva7/show/

**Edit page:** http://jsfiddle.net/honnza/NMva7/

**screenshot:**

[image: fir tree]

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id=c width=200 height=300 style="display:none"></canvas>
<div id=config></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var TAU = 2*Math.PI,
    deg = TAU/360,

    TRUNK_VIEW      = {lineWidth:3, strokeStyle: "brown", zIndex: 1},
    BRANCH_VIEW     = {lineWidth:1, strokeStyle: "green", zIndex: 2},
    TRUNK_SPACING   = 1.5,
    TRUNK_BIAS_STR  = -0.5,
    TRUNK_SLOPE     = 0.25,
    BRANCH_LEN      = 1,
    BRANCH_P        = 0.01,
    MIN_SLOPE       = -5*deg,
    MAX_SLOPE       = 20*deg,
    INIT_SLOPE      = 10*deg,
    MAX_D_SLOPE     =  5*deg,
    DIR_KEEP_BIAS   = 10,
    GROWTH_MSPF     = 10, //ms per frame
    GROWTH_TPF      = 10, //ticks per frame
    ROTATE_MSPF     = 10,
    ROTATE_RPF      = 1*deg; //radians per frame

var configurables = [
//    {key: "TRUNK_SPACING", name: "Branch spacing", widget: "number",
//     description: "Distance between main branches on the trunk, in pixels"},
    {key: "TRUNK_BIAS_STR", name: "Branch distribution", widget: "number",
     description: "Angular distribution between nearby branches. High values tend towards one-sided trees, highly negative values tend towards planar trees. Zero means that branches grow in independent directions."},
    {key: "TRUNK_SLOPE", name: "Trunk slope", widget: "number",
     description: "Amount of horizontal movement of the trunk while growing"},
    {key: "BRANCH_P", name: "Branch frequency", widget: "number",
     description: "Branch frequency - if =1/100, a single twig will branch off approximately once per 100 px"},
    {key: "MIN_SLOPE", name: "Minimum slope", widget: "number", scale: deg,
     description: "Minimum slope of a branch, in degrees"},
    {key: "MAX_SLOPE", name: "Maximum slope", widget: "number", scale: deg,
     description: "Maximum slope of a branch, in degrees"},
    {key: "INIT_SLOPE", name: "Initial slope", widget: "number", scale: deg,
     description: "Angle at which branches leave the trunk"},
    {key: "DIR_KEEP_BIAS", name: "Directional inertia", widget: "number",
     description: "Tendency of twigs to keep their horizontal direction"},
    {get: function(){return maxY}, set: setCanvasSize, name: "Tree height",
     widget:"number"}
    ];

var config = document.getElementById("config"),
    canvas = document.getElementById("c"),
    maxX   = canvas.width/2,
    maxY   = canvas.height,
    canvasRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height,
    c;

function setCanvasSize(height){
    if(height === 'undefined') return maxY;
    maxY = canvas.height = height;
    canvas.width = height * canvasRatio;
    maxX = canvas.width/2;
x}

var nodes = [{x:0, y:0, z:0, dir:'up', isEnd:true}], buds = [nodes[0]],
    branches = [],
    branch,
    trunkDirBias = {x:0, z:0};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

configurables.forEach(function(el){
    var widget;
    switch(el.widget){
        case 'number':
            widget = document.createElement("input");
            if(el.key){
                widget.value = window[el.key] / (el.scale||1);
                el.set = function(value){window[el.key]=value * (el.scale||1)};
            }else{
                widget.value = el.get();
            }
            widget.onblur = function(){
                el.set(+widget.value);
            };
            break;
        default: throw "unknown widget type";
    }
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.textContent = el.name + ": ";
    p.appendChild(widget);
    p.title = el.description;
    config.appendChild(p);
});
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.type = "button";
button.value = "grow";
button.onclick = function(){
    button.value = "stop";
    button.onclick = function(){clearInterval(interval)};
    config.style.display="none";
    canvas.style.display="";
    c=canvas.getContext("2d");
    c.translate(maxX, maxY);                
    c.scale(1, -1);
    interval = setInterval(grow, GROWTH_MSPF);
}
document.body.appendChild(button);
function grow(){
    for(var tick=0; tick<GROWTH_TPF; tick++){
        var budId = 0 | Math.random() * buds.length,
            nodeFrom = buds[budId], nodeTo, branch,
            dir, slope, bias

        if(nodeFrom.dir === 'up' && nodeFrom.isEnd){
            nodeFrom.isEnd = false; 
            rndArg = Math.random()*TAU;
            nodeTo = {
                x:nodeFrom.x + TRUNK_SPACING * TRUNK_SLOPE * Math.sin(rndArg),
                y:nodeFrom.y + TRUNK_SPACING,
                z:nodeFrom.z + TRUNK_SPACING * TRUNK_SLOPE * Math.cos(rndArg), 
                dir:'up', isEnd:true}
            if(nodeTo.y > maxY){
                console.log("end");
                clearInterval(interval);
                rotateInit();
                return;
            }
            nodes.push(nodeTo);
            buds.push(nodeTo);
            branch = {from: nodeFrom, to: nodeTo, view: TRUNK_VIEW};
            branches.push(branch);
            renderBranch(branch);
        }else{ //bud is not a trunk top
            if(!(nodeFrom.dir !== 'up' && Math.random() < BRANCH_P)){
                buds.splice(buds.indexOf(nodeFrom), 1)
            }
            nodeFrom.isEnd = false; 
            if(nodeFrom.dir === 'up'){
                bias = {x:trunkDirBias.x * TRUNK_BIAS_STR,
                        z:trunkDirBias.z * TRUNK_BIAS_STR};
                slope = INIT_SLOPE;
            }else{
                bias = {x:nodeFrom.dir.x * DIR_KEEP_BIAS,
                        z:nodeFrom.dir.z * DIR_KEEP_BIAS};
                slope = nodeFrom.slope;
            }
            var rndLen = Math.random(),
                rndArg = Math.random()*TAU;
            dir = {x: rndLen * Math.sin(rndArg) + bias.x,
                   z: rndLen * Math.cos(rndArg) + bias.z};
            var uvFix = 1/Math.sqrt(dir.x*dir.x + dir.z*dir.z);
            dir = {x:dir.x*uvFix, z:dir.z*uvFix};
            if(nodeFrom.dir === "up") trunkDirBias = dir;
            slope += MAX_D_SLOPE * (2*Math.random() - 1);
            if(slope > MAX_SLOPE) slope = MAX_SLOPE;
            if(slope < MIN_SLOPE) slope = MIN_SLOPE;
            var length = BRANCH_LEN * Math.random();
            nodeTo = {
                x: nodeFrom.x + length * Math.cos(slope) * dir.x,
                y: nodeFrom.y + length * Math.sin(slope),
                z: nodeFrom.z + length * Math.cos(slope) * dir.z,
                dir: dir, slope: slope, isEnd: true
            }
            //if(Math.abs(nodeTo.x)/maxX + nodeTo.y/maxY > 1) return;
            nodes.push(nodeTo);
            buds.push(nodeTo);
            branch = {from: nodeFrom, to: nodeTo, view: BRANCH_VIEW};
            branches.push(branch);
            renderBranch(branch);
        }// end if-is-trunk
    }// end for-tick
}//end func-grow

function rotateInit(){
    branches.sort(function(a,b){
        return (a.view.zIndex-b.view.zIndex);
    });
    interval = setInterval(rotate, ROTATE_MSPF);
}

var time = 0;
var view = {x:1, z:0}
function rotate(){
    time++;
    view = {x: Math.cos(time * ROTATE_RPF),
            z: Math.sin(time * ROTATE_RPF)};
    c.fillStyle = "white"
    c.fillRect(-maxX, 0, 2*maxX, maxY);
    branches.forEach(renderBranch);
    c.stroke();
    c.beginPath();
}

var prevView = null;
function renderBranch(branch){
    if(branch.view !== prevView){
        c.stroke();
        for(k in branch.view) c[k] = branch.view[k];
        c.beginPath();
        prevView = branch.view;
    }
    c.moveTo(view.x * branch.from.x + view.z * branch.from.z,
             branch.from.y);
    c.lineTo(view.x * branch.to.x + view.z * branch.to.z,
             branch.to.y);
}
```

Comment: I know because this answer has only one comment: because it leaves people speechless.

Answer (score 59):

## C++

Let's make it in the spirit of IOCCC and have the code in the shape of a tree as well! :D

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

               int
             main(){
              int a
                ; 
               cin
             >>a;int
           w=a*2+5;for
             (int x=
           0;x<a;++x){
         for(int y=2;y>=
       0;--y){for(int z=0;
           z<a+y-x;++z
        ){cout<<" ";}for(
     int z=0;z<x*2-y*2+5;++z
        ){cout<<".";}cout
      <<endl;}}for(int x=0;
    x<w/5+1;++x){for(int z=0;
  z<w/3+1;++z){cout<<" ";}for(
int z=0;z<w-(w/3+1)*2;z+=1){cout
           <<"#";}cout
           <<endl;;;}}
```

Takes an integer as input, and returns a Christmas tree with that many "stack levels". For example, an input of

```
5
```

Returns:

```
       .
      ...
     .....
      ...
     .....
    .......
     .....
    .......
   .........
    .......
   .........
  ...........
   .........
  ...........
 .............
      ###
      ###
      ###
      ###
```

Comment: output example?

Comment: I put one up now.

Comment: The code looks more like a chrismas tree than the output...

Comment: @dystroy for the record, the instructions do not say it's the output that must containt the tree.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre: But, the size must be adjustable, which is impossible with just the source code. I _could_ make a program that outputs program code in the shape of a Christmas tree that outputs an _actual_ Christmas tree, but I imagine that would be terribly difficult without resorting to just inserting stray semicolons everywhere.

Comment: If you put a `*` at the top of the tree (source code), you will have my +1.

Answer (score 49):

## Bash

Sample output:

[image: ASCII Xmas tree]

The tree size (i.e. number of lines) is passed on the command line, and is limited to values of 5 or greater. The image above was produced from the command `./xmastree.sh 12`. Here's the source code:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a a=('.' '~' "'" 'O' "'" '~' '.' '*')
[[ $# = 0 ]] && s=9 || s=$1
[[ $s -gt 5 ]] || s=5
for (( w=1, r=7, n=1; n<=$s; n++ )) ; do
  for (( i=$s-n; i>0; i-- )) ;  do
    echo -n " "
  done
  for (( i=1; i<=w; i++ )) ; do
    echo -n "${a[r]}"
    [[ $r -gt 5 ]] && r=0 || r=$r+1
  done
  w=$w+2
  echo " "
done;
echo " "
```

Comment: That is very pretty.

Answer (score 42):

Disclaimer: this is based on my LaTeX christmas tree, first posted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87921/8463

The following code will generate a chrismtas tree, with random decorations. You can change both the size of the tree, and the random seed to generate a different tree.

To change the seed modify the value inside `\pgfmathsetseed{\year * 6}` to any other numerical value (the default one will generate a new tree every year)

To change the size of the tree modify the `order=10` to be either larger, or smaller depending on the size of the tree you want.

Examples. `order=11`:

[image]

`order=8`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, lindenmayersystems,shapes,decorations,decorations.shapes}
\begin{document}

\def\pointlistleft{}
\def\pointlistright{}
\pgfmathsetseed{\year * 6}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Christmas tree}{
    \symbol{C}{\pgfgettransform{\t} \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\pointlistleft\expandafter{\expandafter{\t}}}
    \symbol{c}{\pgfgettransform{\t} \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\pointlistright\expandafter{\expandafter{\t}}}
    \rule{S -> [+++G][---g]TS}
    \rule{G -> +H[-G]CL}
    \rule{H -> -G[+H]CL}
    \rule{g -> +h[-g]cL}
    \rule{h -> -g[+h]cL}
    \rule{T -> TL}
    \rule{L -> [-FFF][+FFF]F}
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]
\draw [color=green!50!black,l-system={Christmas tree,step=4pt,angle=16,axiom=LLLLLLSLFFF,order=10,randomize angle percent=20}] lindenmayer system -- cycle;

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{pointsleft}{\pointlistleft}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{pointsright}{\pointlistright}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{colors}{{red}{blue}{yellow}}

\foreach \i in {0,1,...,5}
{
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{pointsleft}
    \pgfsettransform{\c}
    \pgfgettransformentries{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}{\xx}{\yy}
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{pointsright}
    \pgfsettransform{\c}
    \pgfgettransformentries{\a}{\b}{\c}{\d}{\XX}{\YY}
    \pgftransformreset

    \pgfmathsetmacro\calcy{min(\yy,\YY)-max((abs(\yy-\YY))/3,25pt)}

    \draw[draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!50, decorate, decoration={shape backgrounds, shape=star, shape sep=3pt, shape size=4pt}, star points=5] (\xx,\yy) .. controls (\xx,\calcy pt) and (\XX,\calcy pt) .. (\XX,\YY);
}

\foreach \i in {0,1,...,15}
{
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{pointsleft}
    \pgfsettransform{\c}
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations
    \draw[color=black] (0,0) -- (0,-4pt);
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{colors}
    \shadedraw[ball color=\c] (0,-8pt) circle [radius=4pt];
}

\foreach \i in {0,1,...,15}
{
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{pointsright}
    \pgfsettransform{\c}
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations
    \draw[color=black] (0,0) -- (0,-4pt);
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{colors}
    \shadedraw[ball color=\c] (0,-8pt) circle [radius=4pt];
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would say that this is based on Stefan Kottwitz's tree, first posted [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz). Saying that it is based on _your_ tree makes it seem like you wrote all the code for it, which isn't true. Someone else wrote most the code for the actual tree.

Comment: @RyanCarlson the idea to use the lindenmayer system as a basis for putting on decorations was my idea, and if you check carefully both of the code you can see, that the lindenmayer part of the code was redesigned to also have additional parts (like a root for the tree, which the original lacks). Besides that I didn't forget to reference the original, where anyone can check for the references (including the one to Peitgen and Saupe, who might've been the first to draft the equation of the tree)

Answer (score 34):

## Befunge 93

This is an undecorated tree:

```
&::00p20pv
vp010    <
v              p00<
>:0`!#v_" ",1-
v,"/"$<
>10g:2+v
vp01   <
>:0`!#v_" ",1-
v,"\"$<
>91+,00g1-::0`!#v_^
v        *2+1g02<
>:0`!#v_"-",1-
v g02$<
>91+,v
v    <
>:0`!#v_" ",1-
"||"$ <@,,
```

Sample output, input is 10:

```
          /\
         /  \
        /    \
       /      \
      /        \
     /          \
    /            \
   /              \
  /                \
 /                  \
----------------------
          ||
```

Let's add some decorations:

```
&::00p20pv
vp010    <
v              p00<
>:0`!#v_" ",1-
v,"/"$<
>10g:2+v             >"O" v
vp01   <            >?v
>:0`!#v_           >?>>" ">,1-
v,"\"$<             >?<
>91+,00g1-::0`!#v_^  >"*" ^
v        *2+1g02<
>:0`!#v_"-",1-
v g02$<
>91+,v
v    <
>:0`!#v_" ",1-
"||"$ <@,,
```

Sample output:

```
          /\
         /O \
        /    \
       /   ** \
      /     *  \
     /    **   O\
    /* O* *  *   \
   / O      O     \
  / *  **   O*     \
 /   *OO   *  OOO * \
----------------------
          ||
```

Answer (score 32):

## Java

```java
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author Quincunx
 */
public class ChristmasTree {
    public static double scale = 1.2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ChristmasTree();
            }
        });
    }

    public ChristmasTree() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/tree.png");
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

            BufferedImage result = 
                    new BufferedImage((int)(img.getWidth() * scale), 
                            (int) (img.getHeight() * scale), 
                            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) result.getGraphics();
            g.drawRenderedImage(img, AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale));

            JImage image = new JImage(result);
            image.setToolTipText("Not only is that terrible in general, but you "
                    + "just KNOW Billy's going to open the root present first, "
                    + "and then everyone will have to wait while the heap is "
                    + "rebuilt.");
            frame.add(image);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }

    class JImage extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

        BufferedImage img;

        public JImage(){
            this(null);
        }
        public JImage(BufferedImage image){
            img = image;
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));
            addMouseListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(img, WIDTH, WIDTH, this);
        }

        public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
            img = image;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {

        }
    }
}
```

To alter the size, change `scale` to some other double value (keep it around 1 if you want to see anything).

Sample output (for 1.0 as scale, too lazy to take a screenshot, so just posted what it does):

[image]

The program takes this image from the internet, resizes it according to `scale`, then puts it in an undecorated window where it is displayed. Clicking on the window closes the program. Also, the tool tip text is there, but the link is not.

Comment: This isn't "drawing" anything.

Comment: @Mrchief The challenge isn't to draw something; it is to make a tree. This is making a tree, by taking the image

Comment: Did you generate the image yourself? No. You're just downloading it from somewhere. The question isn't to download an image and resize it. Check other answers and you'll understand what the OP actually asked for.

Comment: @Mrchief Did you notice who wrote the OP? This is one of the many possible solutions I was looking for when I asked this question.

Comment: Ha! Smack on the head! Since its your own post, I don't see much reason to argue, other than expressing my opinion that this is not same as your code "making" something (like rest of the answers do). Just like downloading a movie is not the same as making a movie.

Answer (score 32):

## HTML and CSS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Scalable christmas tree</title>
<style>
body {
  background-color: skyblue;
  background-size: 11px 11px, 21px 21px, 31px 31px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 5px 5px,white,rgba(255,255,255,0) 1px), radial-gradient(circle at 5px 5px,white,rgba(255,255,255,0) 2px), radial-gradient(circle at 5px 5px,white 1px,skyblue 1px);
}
div {
  float: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: green;
  border-width: 20px;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 35%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 35%;
  box-shadow: red 0 15px 5px -13px;
  animation-name: light;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: light;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
section {
  float: left;
}
header {
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: red 0 0 10px;
  line-height: .5;
  margin-top: 10px;
  animation-name: star;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: star;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
footer {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 45%, brown 45%, #600 48%, #600 52%, brown 55%, transparent 55%);
}
:target {
  display: none;
}
@keyframes star {
  from { text-shadow: red 0 0 3px; }
  to { text-shadow: red 0 0 30px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes star {
  from { text-shadow: red 0 0 3px; }
  to { text-shadow: red 0 0 30px; }
}
@keyframes light {
  from { box-shadow: red 0 15px 5px -13px; }
  to { box-shadow: blue 0 15px 5px -13px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes light {
  from { box-shadow: red 0 15px 5px -13px; }
  to { box-shadow: blue 0 15px 5px -13px; }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<header>&#x2605;</header>
<div id="0"><div id="1"><div id="2"><div id="3"><div id="4"><div id="5"><div id="6"><div id="7"><div id="8"><div id="9"><div id="10"><div id="11"><div id="12"><div id="13"><div id="14"><div id="15"><div id="16"><div id="17"><div id="18"><div id="19"><div id="20"><div id="21"><div id="22"><div id="23"><div id="24">
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
<footer></footer>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Sizes between 1 and 25 are supported – just add the size to the URL as fragment identifier.

Works in Chrome, Explorer and Firefox. In Opera is ugly, but the scaling part works.

Sample access:

```
http://localhost/xmas.html#5
```

[image: christmas tree of size 5]

Sample access:

```
http://localhost/xmas.html#15
```

[image: christmas tree of size 15]

Live view:

http://dabblet.com/gist/8026898

(The live view contains no vendor prefixed CSS and includes links to change the size.)

Comment: +1 I like the idea of using `:target` to scale the output :-)

Answer (score 28):

## TI-89 Basic

Just because I wanted to see a Christmas Tree on my calculator. I shall type it here as it appears on my calculator.

```
:tree()
:Prgm
:
:Local size
:Prompt size
:
:Local d,x,y,str,orn
:size→x
:0→y
:{" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","°","∫","θ","O","©"}→orn
:size→d
:
:While d≥0
: d-1→d
: ""→str
: 
: While x≥0
:  str&" "→str
:  x-1→x
: EndWhile
: 
: str&"/"→str
: 2*y→x
:
: While x>0
:  str&elementAt(orn,rand(colDim(list▶mat(orn))))→str
:  x-1→x
: EndWhile
: 
: str&"\"→str
: Disp str
: y+1→y
: d→x
:EndWhile
:
:""→str
:
:For x,1,2*(size+2)
: str&"-"→str
:EndFor
:Disp str
:
:""→str
:For x,1,size+1
: str&" "→str
:EndFor
:str&"||"→str
:Disp str
:
:EndPrgm


:elementAt(l,i)
:Func
:Local m
:list▶mat(l)→m
:
:Local cd
:colDim(m)→cd
:
:If i>cd or i≤0 Then
: 1/0
:Else
: If i=cd Then
:  Return sum(mat▶list(subMat(m,1,i))) - sum(mat▶list(subMat(m,1,i+1)))
: Else
:  Return sum(mat▶list(subMat(m,1,i))) - sum(mat▶list(subMat(m,1,i+1)))
: EndIf
:EndIf
:EndFunc
```

This works the same way as my Befunge answer, but I use different ornaments. Yes, my `elementAt` function's repeated uses slows the program down because of many conversions between lists and matrices, but as I wrote it before, I decided against editing it. Also, I learned while typing this answer that `©` makes a comment (I thought it looked like `@`, but that is another character). Never knew what it was before now.

Sample output:

```
size?
7
        /\
       / O\
      /∫   \
     / ©  ∫°\
    / θ ∫   ∫\
   /°  °  ©  ©\
  /O  ∫  O °   \
 / θ  °©  ∫ O  θ\
------------------
        ||
```

I love those `∫`'s; they look like candy canes.

Comment: What version is this?

Comment: @SuperJedi224 I added it to the answer

Answer (score 26):

## Wolfram Language ( *Mathematica* )

As discussed at famed Reddit thread: [t*sin (t) ≈ Christmas tree](http://redd.it/1tswai)

```
PD = .5; s[t_, f_] := t^.6 - f;
 dt[cl_, ps_, sg_, hf_, dp_, f_] := 
    {PointSize[ps], Hue[cl, 1, .6 + sg .4 Sin[hf s[t, f]]], 
     Point[{-sg s[t, f] Sin[s[t, f]], -sg s[t, f] Cos[s[t, f]], dp + s[t, f]}]};

 frames = ParallelTable[

    Graphics3D[Table[{dt[1, .01, -1, 1, 0, f], dt[.45, .01, 1, 1, 0, f], 
                      dt[1, .005, -1, 4, .2, f], dt[.45, .005, 1, 4, .2, f]}, 
 {t, 0, 200, PD}],

     ViewPoint -> Left, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1.3}, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1}, 
    ViewCenter -> {{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5, 0.55}}, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
    PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}, {0, 20}}, Background -> Black],

   {f, 0, 1, .01}];

Export["tree.gif", frames]
```

[image]

Comment: Where you set the size and how it affects the generated tree?

Comment: @manatwork this is basically graph `t*sin(t)` as i said in the post. So plotting for larger t's will just make a bigger tree: `Table[..., {t, 0, 200, PD}]`

Answer (score 24):

## Bash with Bc and ImageMagick

```bash
#!/bin/bash

size="${1:-10}"

width=$(( size*25 ))
height=$(( size*size+size*10 ))

cos=( $( bc -l <<< "for (i=0;i<3.14*2;i+=.05) c(i)*100" ) )
sin=( $( bc -l <<< "for (i=0;i<3.14*2;i+=.05) s(i)*100" ) )
cos=( "${cos[@]%.*}" )
sin=( "${sin[@]%.*}" )

cos=( "${cos[@]/%-/0}" )
sin=( "${sin[@]/%-/0}" )

snow=()
needle=()
decor=()
for ((i=2;i<size+2;i++)); do
  for ((j=3;j<=31;j++)); do
    (( x=width/2+i*10+cos[62-j]*i*10/100 ))
    (( y=i*i+sin[j]*i*5/100 ))

    for ((e=0;e<i;e++)); do
      needle+=(
        -draw "line $x,$y $(( x+RANDOM%i-i/2 )),$(( y+RANDOM%i-i/2 ))"
        -draw "line $(( width-x )),$y $(( width-x+RANDOM%i-i/2 )),$(( y+RANDOM%i-i/2 ))"
      )
    done

    (( RANDOM%2 )) && (( x=width-x ))
    snow+=(
      -draw "circle $x,$(( y-i/2 )) $(( x+i/3 )),$(( y-i/2+i/3 ))"
    )

    (( RANDOM%10 )) || decor+=(
      -fill "rgb($(( RANDOM%5*20+50 )),$(( RANDOM%5*20+50 )),$(( RANDOM%5*20+50 )))"
      -draw "circle $x,$(( y+i )) $(( x+i/2 )),$(( y+i+i/2 ))"
    )
  done
done

flake=()
for ((i=0;i<width*height/100;i++)); do
  flake+=(
    -draw "point $(( RANDOM%width )),$(( RANDOM%height ))"
  )
done

convert \
  -size "${width}x$height" \
  xc:skyblue \
  -stroke white \
  -fill white \
  "${snow[@]}" \
  -blur 5x5 \
  "${flake[@]}" \
  -stroke brown \
  -fill brown \
  -draw "polygon $(( width/2 )),0 $(( width/2-size )),$height, $(( width/2+size )),$height" \
  -stroke green \
  -fill none \
  "${needle[@]}" \
  -stroke none \
  -fill red \
  "${decor[@]}" \
  x:
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ ./xmas.sh 5
```

Sample output:

[image: christmas tree of size 5]

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ ./xmas.sh 15
```

Sample output:

[image: christmas tree of size 15]

Answer (score 22):

**C**

Sample output for depth=4, zoom=2.0

[image: Tree]

This answer employs an approach quite different from other answers. It generates a tree structure by recursively branching. Each branch is represented by a set of circles. And finally the main function samples the circles and fill with characters when circles are met. Since it is done by sampling a scene (like ray-tracing), it is intrinsically scalable. The downside is speed, since it traverse the whole tree structure for every "pixel"!

The first command-line argument controls the depth of branching. And the second controls scale (2 means 200%).

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PI 3.14159265359

float sx, sy;

float sdCircle(float px, float py, float r) {
    float dx = px - sx, dy = py - sy;
    return sqrtf(dx * dx + dy * dy) - r;
}

float opUnion(float d1, float d2) {
    return d1 < d2 ? d1 : d2;
}

#define T px + scale * r * cosf(theta), py + scale * r * sin(theta)

float f(float px, float py, float theta, float scale, int n) {
    float d = 0.0f;
    for (float r = 0.0f; r < 0.8f; r += 0.02f)
        d = opUnion(d, sdCircle(T, 0.05f * scale * (0.95f - r)));

    if (n > 0)
        for (int t = -1; t <= 1; t += 2) {
            float tt = theta + t * 1.8f;
            float ss = scale * 0.9f;
            for (float r = 0.2f; r < 0.8f; r += 0.1f) {
                d = opUnion(d, f(T, tt, ss * 0.5f, n - 1));
                ss *= 0.8f;
            }
        }

    return d;
}

int ribbon() {
    float x = (fmodf(sy, 0.1f) / 0.1f - 0.5f) * 0.5f;
    return sx >= x - 0.05f && sx <= x + 0.05f;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n = argc > 1 ? atoi(argv[1]) : 3;
    float zoom = argc > 2 ? atof(argv[2]) : 1.0f;
    for (sy = 0.8f; sy > 0.0f; sy -= 0.02f / zoom, putchar('\n'))
        for (sx = -0.35f; sx < 0.35f; sx += 0.01f / zoom) {
            if (f(0, 0, PI * 0.5f, 1.0f, n) < 0.0f) {
                if (sy < 0.1f)
                    putchar('.');
                else {
                    if (ribbon())
                        putchar('=');
                    else
                        putchar("............................#j&o"[rand() % 32]);
                }
            }
            else
                putchar(' ');
        }
}
```

Comment: I think it's safe to say this is the most technically impressive answer to this question so far.

Answer (score 20):

## Mathematica ASCII

I really like ASCII art, so I add another very different answer - especially so it's so short in Mathematica:

```
Column[Table[Row[RandomChoice[{"+", ".", "*", "~", "^", "o"}, k]], {k, 1, 35, 2}], 
Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

And now with a bit more sophistication a scalable dynamic ASCII tree. Watch closely - the tree is also changing - snow sticks to branches then falls ;-)

```
DynamicModule[{atoms, tree, pos, snow, p = .8, sz = 15},

 atoms = {
   Style["+", White],
   Style["*", White],
   Style["o", White],
   Style[".", Green],
   Style["~", Green],
   Style["^", Green],
   Style["^", Green]
   };

 pos = Flatten[Table[{m, n}, {m, 18}, {n, 2 m - 1}], 1];

 tree = Table[RandomChoice[atoms, k], {k, 1, 35, 2}];

 snow = Table[
   RotateLeft[ArrayPad[{RandomChoice[atoms[[1 ;; 2]]]}, {0, sz}, " "],
     RandomInteger[sz]], {sz + 1}];

 Dynamic[Refresh[

   Overlay[{

     tree[[Sequence @@ RandomChoice[pos]]] = RandomChoice[atoms];
     Column[Row /@ tree, Alignment -> Center, Background -> Black],

     Grid[
      snow = 
       RotateRight[
        RotateLeft[#, 
           RandomChoice[{(1 - p)/2, p, (1 - p)/2} -> {-1, 0, 1}]] & /@
          snow
        , {1, 0}]]

     }, Alignment -> Center]

   , UpdateInterval -> 0, TrackedSymbols -> {}]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one. Where you adjust the size? Is that 35 in `Table`'s parameters?

Comment: @manatwork yes the 35 in Table. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 19):

I made this for [a challenge on /r/dailyprogrammer](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/1t0r09/121613_challenge_145_easy_tree_generation/), (not sure if reusing code is against the spirit/rules of this) but:

Brainfuck. Takes as input a number (length of bottom row of leaves) and two characters. One space between each.

Example input: 13 = +

Example output:

```
      +
     +++
    +++++
   +++++++
  +++++++++
 +++++++++++
+++++++++++++
     ===
```

Code:

```
                   >
                  ,--
                 -----
                -------
               ---------
              ---------[+
             +++++++++++++
            +++++++++++++++
           +++<[>>++++++++++
          <<-]>--------------
         ---------------------
        -------------[<+>-]>[<<
       +>>-]<,------------------
      --------------],>,,>>++++[<
     ++++++++>-]++++++++++>+<<<<<-
    [>>>>>>+>+<<<<<<<--]>>>>>>>[<<<
   <<<<++>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>[<<<
  .>>>>+<-]>[<+>-]<<[<<<.>>>>>+<<-]>>
 [<<+>>-]<<<.>>><-<++<<<<<--]>>...>>>-
--[>+<<<<..>>>--]<.>>[<<<.>>>>+<-]<<<<<
                ...>>>.
```

Answer (score 16):

### Processing

The original fractal Christmas tree. Mouse Y position determines size, use up and down arrow keys to change the number of generations.

```
int size = 500;

int depth = 10;

void setup() {
  frameRate(30);
  size(size, size, P2D);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  tree(size/2.0, size, 0.0, radians(0), radians(108), (size - mouseY)/3, depth);
  tree(size/2.0, size, 0.0, radians(108), radians(0), (size - mouseY)/3, depth);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if(keyCode == UP) depth++;
  if(keyCode == DOWN) depth--;
  depth = max(depth, 1);
}

void tree(float posX, float posY, float angle, float forkRight, float forkLeft, float length, int generation) {
  if (generation > 0) {
    float nextX = posX + length * sin(angle);
    float nextY = posY - length * cos(angle);

    line(posX, posY, nextX, nextY);

    tree(nextX, nextY, angle + forkRight, forkRight, forkLeft, length*0.6, generation - 1);
    tree(nextX, nextY, angle - forkLeft,  forkRight, forkLeft, length*0.6, generation - 1);
  }
}
```

[image: What a lovely Christmas tree, don't you think, ma?]

```
Or, if you prefer a fuller tree:

int size = 500;

int depth = 10;

void setup() {
  frameRate(30);
  size(size, size, P2D);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  tree(size/2.0 - 5, size, 0.0, 0.0, (size - mouseY)/3, depth);
}

void keyPressed() {
  if(keyCode == UP) depth++;
  if(keyCode == DOWN) depth--;
  depth = max(depth, 1);
}

void tree(float posX, float posY, float angle, float fork, float length, int generation) {
  if (generation > 0) {
    float nextX = posX + length * sin(angle);
    float nextY = posY - length * cos(angle);

    line(posX, posY, nextX, nextY);

    tree(nextX, nextY, angle + fork + radians(108), fork, length*0.6, generation - 1);
    tree(nextX, nextY, angle - fork,                fork, length*0.6, generation - 1);
    tree(nextX, nextY, angle + fork - radians(108), fork, length*0.6, generation - 1);
  }
}
```

[image: I'm super bummed that somebody beat me to posting a fractal tree even though I was was ahead of them in the idea and in actually starting work on it :/]

Answer (score 14):

## Ruby

```
((1..20).to_a+[6]*4).map{|i|puts ('*'*i*2).center(80)}
```

[image: Happy New Year]

You can customize output by changing `*`.
For a green tree: `((1..20).to_a+[6]*4).map{|i|puts "\e[32m"+('*'*i*2).center(80)}`

**Approach 2** (Xmas tree that doesn't look like an arrow)

```
((1..6).to_a+(3..9).to_a+(6..12).to_a+[3]*4).map{|i|puts "\e[32m"+('*'*i*4).center(80)}
```

[image: Happy New Year]

**Approach 3**

```
((1..20).to_a+[6]*4).map{|i|puts' '*(20-i)+'*'*(2*i-1)}
```

Comment: This is more an arrow, then a christmas tree!

Comment: @klingt.net *than.

Comment: Time to light up the christmas tree.

Comment: And where you specify the size?

Comment: @manatwork in ranges. `1..20`, `1..6`, etc.

Comment: Hmm… Changing the range in the second code to `1..20` makes it look like a mushroom.

Comment: @manatwork you may want to change other parts as well to make it proportional. I've adjusted the code with a `size` variable.

Answer (score 14):

### Processing

I made this tree generator using an L-System and a Turtle.

[image: A Tree]

code:

```
//My code, made from scratch:
final int THE_ITERATIONS = 7;
final float SCALE = 1;
final int ANGLE = 130;
final int SIZE = 4;

final int ITERATIONS = THE_ITERATIONS - 1;

int lineLength;

String lSystem;
ArrayList<Turtle> turtles;

int turtleIndex;
int lSystemIndex;

void setup()
{
  size(320, 420);
  background(255);
  translate(width / 2, height - 70);

  lineLength = ITERATIONS * 2 + 2;

  lSystem = "[-F][+F]F";

  turtles = new ArrayList<Turtle>(ITERATIONS + 1);
  lSystemIndex = 0;

  calculateLSystem();
  println(lSystem);

  turtles.add(new Turtle(0, 0));

  doTurtles();
  save("Tree.png");
}

void doTurtles()
{
  while(lSystemIndex < lSystem.length())
  {
    print("\"" + lSystem.charAt(lSystemIndex) + "\": ");
    if(lSystem.charAt(lSystemIndex) == 'F')
    {
      turtleForward();
    }
    else if(lSystem.charAt(lSystemIndex) == '[')
    {
      lineLength -= 2;
      addTurtle();
      println(turtles.size());
    }
    else if(lSystem.charAt(lSystemIndex) == ']')
    {
      lineLength += 2;
      removeTurtle();
      println(turtles.size());
    }
    else if(lSystem.charAt(lSystemIndex) == '+')
    {
      turtleRight();
    }
    else if(lSystem.charAt(lSystemIndex) == '-')
    {
      turtleLeft();
    }
    lSystemIndex++;
  }
}

void addTurtle()
{
  turtles.add(new Turtle(turtles.get(turtles.size() - 1)));
}

void removeTurtle()
{
  turtles.remove(turtles.size() - 1);
}

void turtleLeft()
{
  turtles.get(turtles.size() - 1).left(ANGLE + random(-5, 5));
}

void turtleRight()
{
  turtles.get(turtles.size() - 1).right(ANGLE + random(-5, 5));
}

void turtleForward()
{
  print(turtles.get(turtles.size() - 1) + ": ");
  strokeWeight(min(lineLength / SIZE, 1));
  stroke(5 + random(16), 90 + random(16), 15 + random(16));
  if(turtles.size() == 1)
  {
    strokeWeight(lineLength / 2);
    stroke(100, 75, 25);
  }
  turtles.get(turtles.size() - 1).right(random(-3, 3));
  turtles.get(turtles.size() - 1).forward(lineLength);
}

void calculateLSystem()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++)
  {
    lSystem = lSystem.replaceAll("F", "F[-F][+F][F]");
  }
  lSystem = "FF" + lSystem;
}

void draw()
{

}

//——————————————————————————————————————————————————————
// Turtle code, heavily based on code by Jamie Matthews
// http://j4mie.org/blog/simple-turtle-for-processing/
//——————————————————————————————————————————————————————

class Turtle {
  float x, y; // Current position of the turtle
  float angle = -90; // Current heading of the turtle
  boolean penDown = true; // Is pen down?
  int lineLength;

  // Set up initial position
  Turtle (float xin, float yin) {
    x = xin;
    y = yin;
    //lineLength = lineLengthin;
  }

  Turtle (Turtle turtle) {
    x = turtle.x;
    y = turtle.y;
    angle = turtle.angle;
    //lineLength = turtle.lineLength - 1;
  }

  // Move forward by the specified distance
  void forward (float distance) {
    distance = distance * SIZE * random(0.9, 1.1);
    // Calculate the new position
    float xtarget = x+cos(radians(angle)) * distance;
    float ytarget = y+sin(radians(angle)) * distance;

    // If the pen is down, draw a line to the new position
    if (penDown) line(x, y, xtarget, ytarget);
    println(x + ", " + y + ", " + xtarget + ", " + ytarget);
    // Update position
    x = xtarget;
    y = ytarget;
  }

  // Turn left by given angle
  void left (float turnangle) {
    angle -= turnangle;
    println(angle);
  }

  // Turn right by given angle
  void right (float turnangle) {
    angle += turnangle;
    println(angle);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes! An L-System!

Comment: I agree about it being the most realistic :)

Comment: @Timtech I disagree. I think this is the second most realistic, after [Jan Dvorak's Javascript answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15922/9498). I mean, look at those needles (on this one)! They are all clustered together in patterns that I have not seen on an evergreen tree. However, Jan's tree looks a lot like a fir sapling to me.

Comment: @Quincunx I must have missed that one. Still, this one looks pretty good.

Comment: @Quincunx Jan's tree—and Howard's, too—is really cool, but not necessarily completely _realistic_. Jan even admits that the tree is only "quasirealistic". – [RyanCarlson](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11066/ryancarlson) 10 secs ago

Comment: @RyanCarlson I'd say the same for your tree. It is rather realistic, but not completely realistic. But I still like it (and it is one of the most realistic trees here)

Comment: @Quincunx [I guess you have a good point](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cCzlA.png)

Answer (score 14):

## [Turtle Graphics](https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/apps/turtle/index.html#)

[image]

Based on properties of the [Euler spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral).

Code:

[image]

The scale is determined by the step size (`move forward by: 6`). An interactive version is available [here](https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/apps/turtle/index.html#rjtwyt).

P.S. Inspired by [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18157/13509) question.

Comment: Where is this "scalable"? Other than that, this is great!

Comment: @Quincunx You can change scale by changing `move forward by 6`. For example, `10` will produce a larger tree. Actually there is no input in this "language" (or the whole code can be treated as input ;) ).

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (run on any page in console)

I was golfing this but then decided not to, so as you can see there are TONS of magic numbers :P

```
// size
s = 300

document.write('<canvas id=c width=' + s + ' height=' + s + '>')
c = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d')
c.fillStyle = '#0D0'
for (var i = s / 3; i <= s / 3 * 2; i += s / 6) {
  c.moveTo(s / 2, s / 10)
  c.lineTo(s / 3, i)
  c.lineTo(s / 3 * 2, i)
  c.fill()
}
c.fillStyle = '#DA0'
c.fillRect(s / 2 - s / 20, s / 3 * 2, s / 10, s / 6)
```

Result for s = 300:

[image: screenshot]

s = 600:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you going to decorate the tree? :-)

Comment: @Quincunx Possibly, I may work on that later :)

Comment: GAH! Where are the semicolons?!

Comment: @AndrewLarsson: [Semicolons are not required in JavaScript](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/)

Answer (score 10):

### Game Maker Language

**spr_tree**

[image: spr_tree]

**The tree's Create Event**

```
image_speed=0
size=get_integer("How big do you want me to be?#Integer between 1 and 10, please!",10)
image_index=size-1
```

**Room, 402 by 599**

The tree is placed at `(0,0)`

**Bonus!** You can resize the Christmas tree after the initial input with the keys 0-9.

Answer (score 8):

## AppleScript + SE Answer

Actually picked this up by accident while editing an answer in this question. Go figure.

Use this by running the code, typing in your number that you want, swiping over to the SE post and clicking in the text field. This exploits the fact that quotes stack.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set layers to (display dialog "" default answer "")'s text returned as number
    delay 5
    repeat layers times
        keystroke ">"
    end repeat
end tell
```

Output (input 50):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >

Answer (score 6):

### Decorated FORTRAN tree

```
    character(len=36) :: f='/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\'
    character(len=18) :: g = '                  '
    character(len=14) :: p = ".x$.+oO+oO.#,~"
    character(len=10) :: q

    n = iargc()
    if (n /= 1) then 
        k = len(g)
    else
        call getarg(1,q) 
        read(q,*) k
    end if
    l = modulo(k,len(g))+1
    do i=1,l
        j = mod(i,len(p)-1)+1
        print *,g(1:l-i),p(j:j),f(1:2*i),p(j+1:J+1)
        end do
    print *,g(1:l-1),f(1:4)
    end
```

The tree has a limited range of sizes, but it believe it accurately reflects the life of most Christmas trees.

From infant tree:

```
$./tree
 x/\$
 /\/\
```

To adolescent tree:

```
$./tree 6
       x/\$
      $/\/\.
     ./\/\/\+
    +/\/\/\/\o
   o/\/\/\/\/\O
  O/\/\/\/\/\/\+
 +/\/\/\/\/\/\/\o
       /\/\
```

To adult:

```
$./tree 17
                  x/\$
                 $/\/\.
                ./\/\/\+
               +/\/\/\/\o
              o/\/\/\/\/\O
             O/\/\/\/\/\/\+
            +/\/\/\/\/\/\/\o
           o/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\O
          O/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\.
         ./\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\#
        #/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\,
       ,/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\~
      ./\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\x
     x/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\$
    $/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\.
   ./\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\+
  +/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\o
 o/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\O
                  /\/\
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class ChristmasTree {
    static class Point{
        Point(int a,int b){x=a;y=b;}
        int x,y;
        double distance(Point o){
            int dx=x-o.x;
            int dy=y-o.y;
            return Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
        }
    }
    static int siz;
    static BufferedImage b;
    static Random r=new Random();
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

        if(args.length==0){
            siz=(new Scanner(System.in)).nextInt();
        }else{
            siz=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        b=new BufferedImage(20*siz,30*siz,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g=(Graphics2D)b.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(140,70,20));
        int h=b.getHeight();h*=0.4;
        for(int i=(int)(0.4*b.getWidth());i<(int)(0.6*b.getWidth());i++){
            if(r.nextDouble()<0.3){
                g.drawLine(i,b.getHeight(),i+r.nextInt(2)-1,h);
            }
        }
        for(int i=h;i<b.getHeight();i++){
            if(r.nextDouble()<0.3){
                g.drawLine((int)(0.4*b.getWidth()),i,(int)(0.6*b.getWidth()),i);
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<siz;i++){
            g.setColor(new Color(r.nextInt(4),150+r.nextInt(15),20+r.nextInt(7)));
            g.drawLine(b.getWidth()/2-(int)(b.getWidth()*0.42*i/siz),(int)(b.getHeight()*0.9)+r.nextInt(5)-2,b.getWidth()/2+(int)(b.getWidth()*0.42*i/siz),(int)(b.getHeight()*0.9)+r.nextInt(5)-2);
            g.setColor(new Color(r.nextInt(4),150+r.nextInt(15),20+r.nextInt(7)));
            g.drawLine(b.getWidth()/2-(int)(b.getWidth()*0.42*i/siz),(int)(b.getHeight()*0.9),b.getWidth()/2,(int)(b.getHeight()*(0.1+(.06*i)/siz)));
            g.setColor(new Color(r.nextInt(4),150+r.nextInt(15),20+r.nextInt(7)));
            g.drawLine(b.getWidth()/2+(int)(b.getWidth()*0.42*i/siz),(int)(b.getHeight()*0.9),b.getWidth()/2,(int)(b.getHeight()*(0.1+(.06*i)/siz)));
        }
        g.setColor(new Color(150,120,40));
        g.fillOval((b.getWidth()-siz-2)/2,b.getHeight()/10,siz+2,siz+2);
        g.setColor(new Color(250,240,80));
        g.fillOval((b.getWidth()-siz)/2,b.getHeight()/10,siz,siz);
        List<Color>c=Arrays.asList(new Color(0,255,0),new Color(255,0,0),new Color(130,0,100),new Color(0,0,200),new Color(110,0,200),new Color(200,205,210),new Color(0,240,255),new Color(255,100,0));
        List<Point>pts=new ArrayList<>();
        pts.add(new Point((b.getWidth()-siz)/2,b.getHeight()/10));
        loop:for(int i=0;i<8+siz/4;i++){
            int y=r.nextInt((8*b.getHeight())/11);
            int x=1+(int)(b.getWidth()*0.35*y/((8*b.getHeight())/11));
            x=r.nextInt(2*x)-x+b.getWidth()/2;
            y+=b.getHeight()/8;
            g.setColor(c.get(r.nextInt(c.size())));
            x-=siz/2;
            Point p=new Point(x,y);
            for(Point q:pts){
                if(q.distance(p)<1+2*siz)continue loop;
            }
            pts.add(p);
            g.fillOval(x,y,siz,siz);
        }
        ImageIO.write(b,"png",new File("tree.png"));
    }
}
```

**Sample results:**

Size=3:

[image]

Size=4:

[image]

Size=5:

[image]

Size=12:

[image]

Size=20:

[image]

Comment: I didn't notice this before. Super cool +1

Answer (score 4):

**Rebol**

With a dialect to display the symbols. To change the tree size, just change the parameter of `make-tree`.

```
make-tree: func [int /local tr] [
  tr: copy []
  length: (int * 2) + 3
  repeat i int [
      repeat j 3 [
            ast: to-integer ((i * 2) - 1 + (j * 2) - 2)
            sp: to-integer (length - ast) / 2
            append/dup tr space sp 
            append/dup tr "*" ast 
            append tr lf
      ]
  ]
  append/dup tr space (length - 1) / 2
  append tr "|"
  append tr lf
  tr
]

print make-tree 3
```

[image: a tree with 3 layers]
[image: a tree with 5 layers]

Comment: Where you set the size and how it affects the generated tree?

Comment: @manatwork To change the `tree` block. You can resize it or change some of the symbols at your will.

Comment: @WayneTsui this doesn't conform to the OP's requirements, *"size must be choosable by some input method"* and *"larger inputs should produce a larger tree."*

Comment: a new make-tree function from @kealist

Answer (score 4):

**Python**

```
import sys
w = sys.stdout.write
def t(n,s):
    for i in range(n):
        for a in range(n-i):
            w(" ")
        w("[")
        for l in range(i<<1):
            if i==n-1:
                w("_")
            else:
                w("~")
        w("]")
        print("")
    for o in range(s):
        for i in range(n):
            w(" ")
        print("[]")

t(10, 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Ti-Basic 84

Asks for a size:

```
              :
            Input 
           S:Lbl 1
            S-1→S
              :
             "||
            "+""→
           Str1:" 
             "→Str2
         :Disp Str2+
        "   **":Disp 
       Str2+"  "+"*"+
      Str1+"*":Disp " 
     "+Str1+"*-"+"||-*
    ":Disp Str1+"*--||-
   -*":Disp "   *---||--
  -*":Disp "  *----||----
 *":Disp Str1+"   "+Str2+"
":If S>0:Goto 2:Goto 1:Lbl 
              2
```

Output (size 1):

```
       **
      *||*
     *-||-*
    *--||--*
   *---||---*
  *----||----*
       ||
```

Comment: Where is the size choosable? This is a fixed-size tree

Comment: @Quincunx Fixed.

Comment: -1; you can't just insert arbitrary whitespace into a TI-Basic program.