# Decorate Pascal's Triangle

Tags: code-golf, math, combinatorics, color

Although what is a [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) is well-known and we already can [generate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/generate-pascals-triangle) it, the task is now different:
**Output** \$n\$ first lines of the Pascal's triangle as colored bricks.
Color number is computed as maximal power of \$d\$, that divides the needed-to-color element or \$7\$ if power is more than \$7\$.
Numbered colors are (\$0\$-based): default, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white (default color is 0th, red is 1st, .. white is 7th).

- Any space-filling (I mean not `.`,`'` or `"` or smth small) character
  can be used for bricks, even `'\u2588'`.
- Whitespace before or after the bricks are optional.
- Brick horizontal length (\$1\$ or \$2\$) is your choice.
- You may choose any convenient output method -- ansi text or graphics or HTML or whatever
- If you choose output letters or color numbers instead of coloring the triangle itself, you should specify in the text of your answer which character corresponds to which color, but output wouldn't look so nice)

**Input** Integers \$n\$ and \$d>1\$ in any convenient method.
This is code-golf, the shortest code in each language wins.

[image]

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6281/58974)

Comment: Can I output HTML that would generated the required text?

Comment: Why do we have to use colored characters? Can we e.g. use differemt letters?

Comment: Agree with pronoun. To me, the colored text bit is ["Adding unnecessary fluff"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9384/69880).

Comment: OK see the edits)

Comment: Too bad that `d` doesn't have to be prime, or we could use [Kummer's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem), that the number of factors of `d` in `choose(i+j,j)` is the number of carries when adding `i+j` in base `d`.

Answer (score 9):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>157 153 143 139</s>  135 bytes

*Saved several bytes thanks to @AlexeyBurdin*
*Saved  <s>4</s>  8 more bytes thanks to @ceilingcat*

Outputs with ANSI colors.

```c
long p,a,s,c,L;f(n,d){for(a=0;c=a++-n;puts(""))for(;p=c<a;printf(c<0?" ":"\e[3%dm@@",L),s=++c<1?1:s*a/c-s)for(L=0;p*=d,L<7&s%p<1;L++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxLCsIwFEDRuasIASVpXrBVQfAl6AKyA52EV1MKbRqMn4G4deNnfDmXdEdUyjDFjiXwkIHAYRARWvkM00V4WyNZr5SOmG7XLDiX8hcwWTIe06WP1yDI1HvO@I6fzsf1vB0PBw5OQrZKkWn2zS5Xfkk6/6n7PlNlW3Bmu8jzZBp0Skl8lfvUt2z0fRSSPWeMBbGpga0kzl7lTWHwXS768QE) (no colors on TIO)

#### Example output for \$f(40,2)\$

[image: output]

#### Formula

At row \$r\$ and column \$c-1\$, we have:

$$P_{r,c-1}={r\choose c-1}=\frac{r!}{(c-1)!(r-c+1)!}$$

On the same row and the next column \$c\$, we have:

$$\begin{align}P_{r,c}={r\choose c}&=\frac{r!}{c!(r-c)!}\\
&=\frac{r-c+1}{c}\times\frac{r!}{(c-1)!(r-c+1)!}\\
&=\frac{r-c+1}{c}\times P_{r,c-1}\\
&=\frac{r+1}{c}P_{r,c-1}-P_{r,c-1}\end{align}$$

which is translated as `s = s * a / c - s` in the C code (with \$a=r+1\$).

#### Commented

```c
long p, a, s, c, L;               // declare a few 64-bit integers
f(n, d) {                         // n = number of rows, d = colorization parameter
  for(a = 0; a++ < n; puts(""))   // for a = 1 to n, with a linefeed added after each
    for(                          // iteration:
      c = a + ~n;                 //   for c = a - n - 1 to a - 1:
      p = c < a;                  //
      printf(                     //     update the output after each iteration:
        c < 0 ?                   //       if c is negative:
          " "                     //         just append a space
        :                         //       else:
          "\e[3%dm@@",            //         append the ANSI color code, followed by '@@'
        L                         //       set the 2nd digit of the color code
      ),                          //
      s = ++c < 1 ? 1             //     increment c; set s to 1 while c is less than 1
                  : s * a / c - s //     then, update s to s * a / c - s
    )                             //
      for(                        //       compute the color L:
        L = 0;                    //         start with L = 0
        p *= d,                   //         multiply p by d
        L < 7 & s % p < 1;        //         stop if L = 7 or p does not divide s
        L++                       //         increment L
      );                          //
}                                 //
```

Comment: Impressive. I thought default color is 39, not 97, so you can golf 3 bytes, nm.

Comment: Is the case of power of d being more than 7 really covered by `l=s%p?l:A`? Anyway, computing the triangle with only 7 bytes `s*a/c-s` is pretty much impressive. Can you write some comments on how the things work?)

Comment: Not sure it's 100% working. Maybe `for(A=0,p=d;!(s%p);A++,p*=d)` and using `A` as `L` would be better. And I do especially want to know how `s = s * a / c - s` generates the pascal triangle) Thanks

Comment: Hmm thanks for incorporating my thoughts into your solution. `L?L:9` is not needed now?)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Given that using colors is now optional, I made the assumption that we may just as well use any color for the 'default' one. But I can revert that change if that's invalid.

Comment: I think it's OK

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I've finally added an explanation of the formula. (Sorry, I'm very slow today.)

Comment: I've already got +1 and 2 answers for [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3447787) but thanks))

Comment: -5 if you declare f(n,d,p,a,s,c,L)

Comment: @GB It would fail much earlier with 32-bit variables, though.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>158</s> <s>134</s> 132 bytes

```python
n,d=input()
o=r=[1]
exec"print''.join([`i`for i in range(8)if c%d**i<1][-1]*2for c in r).center(2*n);r=o+map(sum,zip(r,r[1:]))+o;"*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrRCsIgFADQ975CBjF1NlJ6iJZfIsKGc3WDXeXmoPp5o87zye9yT2hqRTVbwLwVLnbJknXa7@IrhiYTYGnb/pEAuRthXBIxYICMJrxFfhawsLCfpYSr9u6gvTS/Ev5F9CFiicSNRDGQTd06Zf7cVvWBzEmR0xcvRJeGRmKtp6MyXw)

22 bytes from tips by [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Uses `01234567` as the 8 characters instead of 8 colors.

Comment: `'%d'%i` to save 7 [TIO](https://tio.run/##HcxNDoIwEEDhvadoSEh/qMQ2LgzISZouoBQdF0MzqYl6@Qrsv/fSNz9XtKWgngfA9M5Cnmhwxp/iJ4YqEWDmvH2tgMLxeuY1sGUlBgyQ0YiPKG4SFhbqWSm4G@/Oxiu7k3AQ2YaIOZKwCmV/rBs3NtNxGfW0ox8kQa7bSk3OdF5uxPi@UljK9aLtHw).

Comment: `r=[1]+map(sum,zip(r,r[1:]))+[1]` for 13 more :)

Comment: Ah backticks - even better :)

Comment: @Jonathan Allan: Yep! Good call on the others; I was spacing with the `r[:-1]`... :)

Comment: 2 more with `o=r=[1]` and `r=o+map(sum,zip(r,r[1:]))+o`

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
ÝεyÝcI7LmδÖO}».c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//8OdzrV5w51jSTdMbc60w5ZPfcK7LmP//zQwCjI)

```
Ý                 # range 0..input
 ε          }     # for each number y in that range:
  yÝ              #  range 0..y
    c             #  binomial coefficient (yields a row of the triangle)
     I            #  second input
      7L          #  range 1..7
        m         #  power (yields [input, input², ..., input**7])
         δÖ       #  double-vectorized divisible-by
           O      #  sum each inner list
»                 # join by newlines, joining sublists by spaces
 .c               # center
```

#### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes, no binomial coefficient built-in

```
1λ£0ªDÁ+}εI7LmδÖOºJ}.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8NzuQ4sNDq1yOdyoXXtuq6e5T@65LYen@R/a5VWrlwyUN@AyAgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
1Ø0j+ƝƊ⁸Ð¡Ṗọ«7ịØaḤz⁶ZṚ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP9qZWxsef//McOYMGorxp3GiuKBuMOQwqHhuZbhu43Cqzfhu4vDmGHhuKR64oG2WuG5muKCrP/Dp1n//zIw/zI)

A full program taking the number of rows as its first argument and the power as its second. Outputs the triangle to STDOUT. Colours are represented by `z` for 0/default and `a` to `g` for 1 to 7+.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>41</s> <s>36</s> <s>32</s>  <s>29</s>  25 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
_p1 ä+T}h[]à)m£_XuVpZa7}f
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=X3AxIOQrVH1oW13gKW2jX1h1VnBaYTd9Zg&footer=rm1hNyC4w7f7&input=MjAKMw)

```
      h   )  // run input times
       []à   // starting with empty 2d array (permutations of [])

_    }       // function that:
 p1          // appends 1
    T        // and prepends 0
  ä+         // sums consecutive elements
      

m            // for each line
 £           // for each element
           f // find first number (starting at 0) that return false this function:  
  _       }  // f(Z)
   Xu        // triangle element modulo
     Vp      // 2nd input raised to  
       Za8   // absolute difference
```

Uses numbers [7...0] as colors
Footer inverts colors to [0...7] for simpler output

Saved a lot thanks to @Shaggy

Comment: [24 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=X7LkK1R9aFtOpF0gbaNfWHVWcFphOH1m&footer=bbi3%2bw&input=MjAKMg)?

Comment: @Shaggy good! I think you should post your own answer since it's a different approach, anyway I'm gonna steal the ä+0 from you , I also think outputting [7...0] is valid but I'm gonna leave as [0...7] bcuz it's more clear

Comment: No, you work away, buddy - all's I've done is golf your method. Besides, I haven't read the spec nor fully tested my version!

Comment: You could change the digits used in the footer, [like so](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=X7LkK1R9aFtOpF0gbaNfWHVWcFphOH1m&footer=rm1hNyC4w7f7&input=MjAKMg). Or, if you *do* want to retain them in your solution, you can still save a byte with `£7a_` to avoid the last space.

Comment: Or, better yet, without needing to do anything in the footer: `Ë£_XuVpZ}fa7`

Comment: Thanks @Shaggy, gonna use your suggestion then, there's only one thing I can't understand.. N¤ ..

Comment: [[]] works well too

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>24</s> 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
FNNÝcεU7ÝR.ΔmXsÖ])».c
```

First input is the amount of rows `n`, second input the power-base `d`.
Outputs `[0,7]` instead of the colors, and only outputs a single digit for the bricks (with spaces).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//0ZOTsOdY861VTfDnVIuzpRtWHPDll0pwrsuY///NDAKMg)

**Explanation:**

```python
F                # Loop in the range [0, (implicit) input n):
 NN              #  Push the current loop-index twice
   Ý             #  Pop the top one, and create a list in the range [0, index]
    c            #  Calculate the binomial coefficient of the index and this ranged list
                 #   i.e. 10 choose [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
                 #    → [1,9,36,84,126,126,84,36,9,1]
    ε            #  Map each value to:
     U           #   Pop and store the current value in variable `X`
      7Ý         #   Push a list in the range [0,7]
        R        #   Reverse it to make the range [7,0]
         .Δ      #   Find the first digit which is truthy for:
           m     #    Take the (implicit) input d to the power of the current digit
            Xs   #    Push variable `X` and swap the two values
              Ö  #    Check if `X` is divisible by this digit ** `d`
]                # Close the find_first; map; and loop
 )               # Wrap all lists into a list
  »              # Join each inner list by spaces, and then each string by newlines
   .c            # Centralize the lines by padding leading spaces
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: How did I miss `c` >.>

Comment: @Grimmy I remembered [golfing an 05AB1E answer for the Pascal Triangle challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/generate-pascals-triangle?page=2&tab=votes#comment460888_155161) which was using `c`. I'm not too happy with my `εU7ÝR.ΔmXsÖ]` part, though. But I'm looking forward seeing a potential golf of your answer now that you know about `c`. ;)

Comment: [Yup I'm down to 17 now](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196362/6484)

Comment: @Grimmy Nice! As always you're completely overshadowing me with your lower byte-count, haha. ;p

Comment: Note that all the bytes I save are on the color computation. `FNNÝcI7LmδÖO})».c` would also be 17 and much closer to your approach.

Comment: @Grimmy Yeah, ik.. That was also the part I wasn't happy about when I posted my answer. Generating the Pascal Triangle numbers and pretty-printing it into a triangle were ok.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
Ｎθ⊞υ¹ＦＮ«Ｐ⭆υ×¹¹ΣＥ⁸¬﹪κＸθμ↙⊞υ⁰ＵＭυ⁺κ§υ⊖λ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCsIwDIDP7il6zKDCJh7EncRdBCeD@QJ1i27YNrNrVRCfva7@gLkkfEm@pG6FqUlI7ze6d3bn1AENXOIsKt3QguMsHesjGQb/A3HMHtGkcNJ2vem0hcqO6VSIPqzsO4UDpClnlVMQ4IKzHVkoqHGS4MxZSbdwhzMVfyMbfXRFWOZ001s82kB@TyTvtujXpJTQTUCldEMwrexGN3gPKMfaoEJtsQH5cT69n0XzxE@v8gU) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the number of rows as the second input. Output uses digits `1-8` to represent the colours (`1` = default). Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the base.

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start the first row with a single `1`.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Loop over each row.

```
Ｐ⭆υ×¹¹ΣＥ⁸¬﹪κＸθμ↙
```

For each cell, determine its divisibility by the first 8 powers of the base, and take the sum. Then multiply by 11 to duplicate the digit. (Alternatively, casting to string and then duplicating the digit also works.) Don't move the cursor while printing, instead finish by moving the cursor down and left.

```
⊞υ⁰ＵＭυ⁺κ§υ⊖λ
```

Add another column to the row and calculate each row as the sum of the two cells above.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 123 bytes

```ruby
->n,d{(0..n).map{|w|' '*(n-w)+(0..w).map{|i|"\e[#{30+(b=[*1..w].combination(i).size).downto(0).find{|w|b%d**w<1}}m##"}*''}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxLCoMwFEDRrYih5KM@Yp3WbiR1YBqFDPIiNRJazdrTCp2eC/e16Xee@9zcsTY7kwDIwY3LfsSDFlQwbCKvTo9/t0f5mBTZO1kx3SvR/tIAT@@0xTFYj8xyWO1n4mB8xOCZ5DBbNOdSX4wQ8dam5Agpk6A0pbxsYS1m1cr6OuQv)