# Implement Enigma Cipher

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to implement an [Enigma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine) encryption machine. Your program will accept the machine initialization information followed by a string of text to be encrypted.

Initialization vector will be

1. Rotors used (Left to right). Will be three characters. Rotors 1-5 are valid.
2. Initial rotor settings (A-Z) Left to right.
3. Ring Setting, Left to Right.
4. Number of plugs (0-13)
5. N pairs for the plugboard.

After the initialization vector, encrypt all text until a newline (0xA) character is encountered. Any text not in the A-Z range (including lower case for simplicity) should be output as is.

You can compare output against 
[this simulator.](http://startpad.googlecode.com/hg/labs/js/enigma/enigma-sim.html) The initialization vecotr for the default state is `123MCKAAA0`

If you click 'set from passkey' and enter 'codegolf', your equivalent initialization vector is `245FZPPAM10FTJQAOHGMYCKWRIXVPES` With this setting, `baaaaaaaaaaa...` should translate to 
`OXVXI NSRPS RGUXY XZVGB QUNJH TWTVD JNPSI TBWKJ XCVNR IUUVK LJWXV OMCGL VQOKD TVJVW HCFZF DBDQS FYECN SDTPC GESYN OWGNZ WWSYQ WJJBT GVMQM GUUVC XZNCV EPGLM MCNHY KLRJC LISZZ PTYIZ GIEUP OPZUI DPZZZ ULXFZ ONGRI WETGU CICMT KKQBW ZJMNL BZSLJ TLMGR RMZDZ BCNGM RYRGJ MKXRF JKQGG PYZFD UUZRE EIKPD OFUPE XODND DFXKY OHXHX ODWDC SXFPV`. This should fully test a double stepping scenario.

You may assume the Initialization vector will be valid. Rotors will be in required range, no letter will be used in multiple plugs, etc. Only Reflector B will be used.

All needed info (rotor wirings etc...) must be included in your program, not fetched from an outside source. Most details you need are on [wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_rotor_details)

Shortest code wins.

Comment: This question is missing a specification of the procedure for encrypting the text.

Comment: The encryption details are specified in the Wikipedia links specified, as well as elsewhere on the web. What details would you like put here?

Comment: @CMP All details necessary to compete in the challenge. Challenge should be self-contained.

Comment: @MartinBüttner, that doesn't always seem practical. should http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/emulate-an-intel-8086-cpu have included the entire 8086 spec?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Normally, you'd be correct, but in this case, it would be impractical.

Comment: @CMP If it's too much spec to include in the challenge, then you should consider if it's too much to be implemented for an interesting code golf challenge.

Comment: (To be clear, I *don't* think Enigma encryption is too much for an interesting code golf, but I also think the relevant information can be condensed sufficiently to fit nicely into the challenge spec, and you'd still have a much shorter specification than some other challenges. Just saying, if it doesn't fit in the challenge body, it's probably too elaborate to begin with.)

Comment: x87 spec > enigma spec.  Also at a quick glance, the x86 specs are much more technically concise than the enigma wikipedia page, so should require less interpretation.  Also the x86 challenge is [tag:code-challenge] which tends to have less strict requirements than [tag:code-golf]. Having said that, I don't think these are necessarily hard-and-fast rules; generally community consensus is the best guide to what is required in the face of ambiguity.

Comment: I will work on adding some details.

Comment: oops - `s/x87 spec/x86 spec/`

Comment: More than an exact spec, I'd like to see a well-written reference implementation.

Comment: Alright, I'll come back with a better writeup.